# GarbageCollector, Dispose or static Methods?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, dispose

I developed a few classes last month. They grow big (round 30-40 Methods each class).

I never take a thought of Memory Leaks, GarbageColletor or something like this (I must say this is my first own big project).

Now I have classes with Methods, 15 Classes Round About, each class min. 20 methods. 50% are Linq-Classes in the DAL, 50% BusinessClasses with BusinessLogic. NO Class uses global variables (no need), so theoretically I can make them static classes + methods. At the moment they aren't, I initialize a class object and use the class - and not disposing it.

Where I should start when I be angry of having Memory Leaks etc. when the system runs by ~100 users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about the methods of your classes since they do not consume memory: each method exists only once, in the class definition. What really takes memory is the data contained in the objects in the form of fields.

About disposing objects (I assume .NET here), it is not necessary unless you use unmanaged resources. The garbage collector will take care of freeing all the managed resources (that is, plain objects with their data) when necessary.

If you want more information about the .NET garbage collector and how to deal with memory leaks, you can for example look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx. But if you are at the start of your project, I would concentrate on getting a clear and maintainable design, rather than on memory management issues.

Comment: Unfortunately your statement about unmanaged resources is only true if you include such things as "adding an object to a long-lived list" in your definition of an "unmanaged resource". It is quite common for memory leaks to occur in CLR/Java apps because of an event (or observer pattern) that is not torn down when no longer needed.

Comment: Another comment about the statement: "About disposing objects, it is not necessary unless you use unmanaged resources." This is not true. You must also dispose any _managed_ resources which implement the IDisposable interface that you own.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can make a class `static` does not depend on the use of 'global' variables but on the fact if a class uses instance fields (class member variables). If your methods do not use instance data the can be static (and there is a light preference to do so). If all methods are static you can make the class static as well.

Comment: Yeah I know and mean that, but what is - memory thinking - the pro for doing it?

Comment: Kowu, it doesn't sound as if you have a memory problem, just make sure you write correct code. .NET memory handling is easy but not as simple as using static or something.